# Violation of Fajans' rule

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solid-state-chemistry

According to [Fajans' rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fajans'_rules), greater charge in an ionic compound results in more covalent character. But why is it that sodium oxide is more covalent than magnesium oxide? Google says boiling point of magnesium oxide is more than sodium oxide.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86331/when-comparing-boiling-points-of-two-ionic-compounds-what-bonding-factors-shoul........maybe this would help

Comment: Kindly look for similar questions before asking..cause these questions are very likely to get reported as duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When comparing boiling points of two ionic compounds, what bonding factors should you assess?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86331/when-comparing-boiling-points-of-two-ionic-compounds-what-bonding-factors-shoul)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/64974

Comment: Sodium oxide has less electrostatic binding than magnesium oxide, if both are 100% ionic.  Higher cation charge and more favorable stoichionetry with magnesium.